# Como é o processo de instalação do certificado da letsencrypt.org no Linux em servidores Apache?

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https

Gostei muito da ideia de usar o certificado da [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/). Encontrei vários tutoriais na internet, inclusive [esse](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) na Digital Ocean.

Todos os passos funcionaram corretamente, mas como não domino muito a língua inglesa gostaria de mais detalhamento sobre esses passos. Entre as dúvidas estão:

- Onde são obtidos os certificados?
- Por que é necessário inserir um e-mail?
- Qual a diferença entre `chain.pem` e `fullchain.pem`?

Meu objetivo é obter um entendimento mais profundo sobre este processo.

Comment: Wallace, você conseguiu instalar, mas gostaria de entender mais sobre o processo de instalação?

Comment: @WilliamPereira gostaria de entender mais o que está sendo feito nas entrelinhas. Eu por exemplo sei que o `cert-auto` faz todo o processo automatizado para o Apache, mas de onde é que ele pega os certificados? Por que tenho que colocar um e-mail? Qual é a diferença entre o `chain.pem` e o `fullchain.pem`?

Comment: Entendi, eu vou dar uma estudada no processo de instalação dele (eu ja utilizo o serviço) para dar uma boa resposta sobre o assunto.

Comment: Wallace, eu melhorei um pouco a pergunta para focar no objetivo seu que é saber como funciona o processo de instalação e coloquei as perguntas que você comentou aqui, se nao se importar.

Comment: Wallace, eu fiz um passo a passo há um tempo para configurar o apache com o certificado. Neste momento ainda não posso transcrever a resposta para cá, mas espero que ajude. http://www.andremesquita.com/tenha-seu-site-wordpress-com-ssl-gratuitamente/

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá:

## Como os certificados são gerados

O Let's Encrypt tem uma Autoridade Certificadora (CA) que assina os certificados gerados pelos agents instalados nas máquinas que estão sendo validadas. Essa CA é confiável por todas as outras CA's e é isso que garante que a validade do certificado.

Antes de emitir o certificado, o Let's Encrypt valida se o controle do host e também as chaves desse host são realmente da pessoa ou serviço que está requisitando o certificado através de uma série de desafios que não vou deixar aqui para fazer a resposta mais sucinta.

Quando as chaves são validadas, o LE envia uma request para o CA e pede a validação do certificado usando a chaves RSA que foram validadas e esse certificado é armazenado na máquina.

## Por que é necessário inserir um e-mail

O email é somente necessário para que o LE envie para você uma notificação quando os certificados estão expirando. Lembrando que, como os certificados são gratuitos, a validade dos mesmos é de apenas 3 meses, e você não pode validar eles previamente, somente quando está a um determinado numero de dias do certificado vencer.

Então, quando seus certificados estão prestes a vencer, eles te mandam um email avisando.

## Chain e FullChain

O arquivo `chain.pem` é a cadeia de confiança de certificados até chegar no seu certificado.

O `fullchain.pem` é somente a concatenação do seu certificado com o arquivo `chain.pem`.

Espero que tenha sido esclarecedor! Se você quiser saber mais, o LE tem uma página que descreve em detalhes o funcionamento do sistema: https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/